# getting segmentation fault in assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, segmentation-fault, intel-syntax

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.

I am using this assembly program:
and for some reason I'm getting a segmentation fault, is it related to the stack? What does this program even supposed to output? somebody told me to run it and see what it does, any ideas? 
I thought it would be problematic and made a post about it, but it wasn't a problem, I tried debugging it with GDB and that didn't really help. If you could tell me what it outputs it would probably even be better, that's what I'm really looking for

```
.code32
.intel_syntax noprefix

.global _start

_start:
      mov eax, 0x04
      push eax
      mov eax, 0x2d
      push eax
      call asm2

asm2:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 0x10
    mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp + 0xc] --- seg fault here
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4], eax
    mov eax, DWORD PTR[ebp+0x8]
    mov DWORD PTR [ebp-0x8], eax
    jmp part_b

part_a:
     add DWORD PTR [ebp - 0x4], 0x1
     add DWORD PTR [ebp + 0x8], 0x64
part_b:
     cmp DWORD PTR [ebp+0x8], 0x1d89
     jle part_a
     mov eax, DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
     mov esp, ebp
     pop ebp
     ret
```

Comment: You can't `ret` from `_start`, which is what happens after `call asm2` returns and then execution falls through into `asm2` again.

Comment: oops, just noticed you're getting a segfault before you get to `ret`.  Is that on the first time through the function, or did it already run once and then fall through into `asm2`?  What value does EBP have at that point?